# Do I need create a session in my code to run parallel tests in Jenkins ?

Tags: jenkins, thread-safety, jbehave, session-management, parallel-testing

I am about to run parallel tests on my automation project (I am using Jbehave), but I would like to know if I need create a session management (Thread managements) in my code or if Jenkins can do this for me. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Following plugins to achieve your task:

[Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)

[Multijob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)

Comment: Thanks !! So, I don't need to code anything, just install the plugins ?

Comment: You don't need write any code ,when using  Multijob . but in build flow you should use some dsl scripts.

Comment: dsl script example - build("jobname")

Answer (score 0):

You can run both sequential and parallel jobs with the help of build flow job.

example:

pipeline job:

```
    build("job1")
    build("job2")
```

parallel job:

```
    parallel(
       build("job1")
       build("job2")
       )
```